# Java "trick", redefining daughter class member

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm training for a Java exam, and I've come across something I don't understand in last year subject. Here is the code

```
class Mother {
    int var = 2;

    int getVar() {
        return var;
    }
}

class Daughter extends Mother {
    int var = 1;

    int getVar() { 
        return var;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mother m = new Mother();
        System.out.println(m.var);
        System.out.println(m.getVar());
        m = new Daughter();
        System.out.println(m.var);
        System.out.println(m.getVar());
    }
}
```

The question is "what is the output of this program?". I would have go with 2 2 1 1, but when compiling and running this piece of code, I get 2 2 2 1.

Anyone can explain me why ?

Thanks for reading !

Comment: `Daughter` extends `Mother`? that's quite weird, as in reality it's the other way round.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the reason too. I ran this in Eclipse and checked the values with debugger, the debugger actually shows the local m -variable having TWO different var -members after the m = new Daugher() -line. m.var seems to resolve to the one in Mother (maybe because the local variable is declared as Mother, not sure?), and the m.getVar() calls the getVar in Daughter (as expected).

Comment: Note that in real programs this wouldn't happen, because normally you would make `var` private. And if ever you would make it accessible from outside the class, which should be very rare, then you should make sure that variables don't hide each other.

Comment: Not all daughters are mothers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The method call `m.getVar()` is a virtual method call. The second time you call it, it's dynamically dispatched to the derived `Daughter.getVar()`, which does what you expect (accesses `Daugther.var` and returns that).

There is no such virtual dispatch mechanism for member fields. So `m.var` always refers to `Mother.var`, i.e. the base class's version of that variable.

The `Daughter` class can be seen as having two different `var` member: the one from `Mother` and its own. Its own member "hides" the one in `Mother`, but can be accessed from within the `Daughter` class by using `super.var`.

The official spec for this is in section [8.3 Field Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#40898) of the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/jTOC.doc.html).
Quote:

> If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to *hide* any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class. The field declaration also shadows (§6.3.1) declarations of any accessible fields in enclosing classes or interfaces, and any local variables, formal method parameters, and exception handler parameters with the same name in any enclosing blocks.

Note that it can get pretty interesting (emphasis added):

> If a field declaration hides the declaration of another field, the *two fields need not have the same type*.

And:

> *There might be several paths by which the same field declaration might be inherited from an interface*. In such a situation, the field is considered to be inherited only once, and it may be referred to by its simple name without ambiguity.

So that paragraph is well worth reading :-)

Comment: So if I get it right, when a derived class redefines a member field, accessing this field directly will return the parent class field, while accessing it through a method will return the right field. Is that it ?

Comment: not exactly. Depends on how you are accessing it. If your object is referenced as Daughter then you will access the derived class field

Comment: depends on the type of the reference you're using. If you had used `Daughter d = new Daugther(); System.out.println(d.var);` would obviously have returned `1`.

Comment: @Mat so there are two copies of var? one for Mother and one for Daughter?

Comment: @AtoMerZ: yes, that's the case. You can actually access the parent class's field in the daughter class by using `super.var`.

Comment: @Katen: In accessing the field, it depends on the (compile time) type of the *object before the dot*. In the direct case, the variable is of type `Mother`. In the indirect case, it is accessed inside a method of `Daughter`, which accesses the `Daughter.var` variable instead (since `this` is of type `Daughter`).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It's still weird but now at least I know why.

Answer (score 6):

Focus on these lines:

```
Mother m;
 m = new Daughter();
 System.out.println(m.var);
 System.out.println(m.getVar());
```

You are constructing a Daughter object, but you are treating it like it's base class Mother. So when you access m.var you are accessing the base class variable var. Meanwhile when you call a method, even if you are referring to the base class reference, the overrided method is called.
It's a different behavior for methods and fields.. Fields reference cannot be overrided.

Answer (score 2):

Methods can be overridden however fields can only be hidden. The difference is that a non-static method uses the type of the object referenced, a field takes the type of the reference.  You see a similar thing with static methods which only be hidden where the class of the "reference" and the object (if provided) is ignored.

For your interest, try giving the fields different types. ;)

You can also try

```
System.out.println(((Mother)m).var); // uses var in Mother
System.out.println(((Daughter)m).var); // uses var in Daughter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = new Daughter();
```

Though you have created a `daughter` object, you are referring that object with `Mother m` reference. So, any call using `m` will call the Mother class members, not daughter's

Answer (score 0):

I ran this in Eclipse and checked the values with debugger, the debugger actually shows the local `m` -variable having TWO different var -members after the `m = new Daugher()` -line with values 2 and 1. `m.var` seems to resolve to the one in Mother, and the m.getVar() calls the getVar in Daughter (as expected).

However, when I change the main-method to look like this:

```
    Mother m = new Mother();
    System.out.println(m.var);
    System.out.println(m.getVar());
    Daughter d = new Daughter();
    System.out.println(d.var);
    System.out.println(d.getVar());
```

It actually outputs 2, 2, 1, 1, so it would seem that the declaration of the variable affects which class's `var` is used.

Answer (score 0):

I read the answers and non of them (so far) gave good reason why in Object oriented language as Java is, this should be the case. I will try to explain.

Suppose that you have function that takes Mother as arg:

```
void foo(Mother m) {
  print(m.var);
}
```

This function (actually the compiler) has no idea if you will call it with `Mother`, `Daughter` ***or with another `Dauther2` that doesn't even have `var` variable declared***. Because of that, when the reference is of type Mother, reference to a member variable must be linked (by the compiler) to the `Mother`'s member. *The similar applies to function too*, so the functions are linked to Mother's ***declaration*** of `getVar()`, but not to `Mother`'s ***implementation*** of `getVar()`

So, member variables are always linked (by the compiler) based on the reference. Another way to explain it: If you remove `Mother`'s var (and make Mother's `getVar()` compilable), your **second `m.var` (when m refers to Daughter) *won't compile*** even `Daughter` has member var.

I hope i was clear.